# Python paramiko sudo doesnt work

Tags: python, ssh, sudo, paramiko

I am trying automate linux administration using Python Paramiko ssh module, everything working fine except sudo. I followed the paramiko documentation for sudo using `stdin.write()` and `stdin.flush()` but no luck so far.Please help me on this.

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(host,username=uname,password=pwd)
print('Successfully authenticated on'+ " " +host)            
print "\n"
stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command('sudo ls')
stdin.write(pwd+'\n')
stdin.flush()
print stdout.readlines()
ssh.close()
```

Comment: you got any error, or no output?

Comment: I dint get any erros, i see as below
Successfully authenticated on 192.168.1.19


[]

Comment: please try to run same command on console, have you got any fine in that? This may happen if there is not file in current directory.

Answer (score 1):

sudo behaves in very specific ways regarding the TTY you're on, in order to maintain its idea of security. There is a command line option to write the prompt to `stderr` and read from `stdin`, instead of sudo dealing with the TTY directly.

Try:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('sudo -S ls')
```

If you're doing this for system administration tasks, a lot of the framework has already been done. You could have a look at [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/)  if you're happy writing python for most things, or something like [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com/) to still control things over `ssh` but write policy in a simpler `yaml` format.

Comment: wow .. stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command('sudo -S ls') did work. 
Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [atexit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html) module. It cleans my functions on exit.
I use it like this: `atexit.register(client.close)`